# partial_run() requires empty target_list

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want run sensor step by step in tensorflow, so I use the partial_run_setup and partial_run. And this code run with no error:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder("float")
feed = {x: 3.0}
a = tf.Variable(1.0)
b = tf.Variable(2.0)
o1=tf.add(a,x)
o2=tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(0.1).minimize(o1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(o2,feed))
```

But this code show error:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder("float")
feed = {x: 3.0}
a = tf.Variable(1.0)
b = tf.Variable(2.0)
o1=tf.add(a,x)
o2=tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(0.1).minimize(o1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    h = sess.partial_run_setup([o1, o2], [x])
    print(sess.partial_run(h, o1,feed))
    print(sess.partial_run(h, o2,feed))
```

And error list:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(sess.partial_run(h, o2,feed))
  File "/home/zhcong/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 945, in partial_run
    return self._run(handle, fetches, feed_dict, None, None)
  File "/home/zhcong/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1120, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/zhcong/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1319, in _do_run
    return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feeds, fetches)
  File "/home/zhcong/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1323, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/zhcong/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1306, in _prun_fn
    raise RuntimeError('partial_run() requires empty target_list.')
RuntimeError: partial_run() requires empty target_list.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow partial_run does not accept optimizer as fetch. You can use

```
with tf.control_dependencies([o2]):
  dummy = tf.constant(0)
```

and pass dummy in partial_run

Check this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1899